# R coding - Using Log() in auto.arima() - Do I need to do an anti-log() after forecast?

Tags: r, arima

I am new to time series and I tried my hand at `auto.arima()` on the log() of a Time series dataThen, I used `forecast()` from the forecast package and when I plotted it, I saw that the data was in the range < 10. So I feel this indicates that the data is still in Log(). So now how do I do an anti-log()?

Or am I going wrong somewhere?

**Reference code:**

```
log_pautoarima=auto.arima(y=log(paddy_ts))
summary(log_pautoarima)
Series: log(paddy_ts)
ARIMA(1,1,2)

Coefficients:
         ar1 ma1 ma2
      0.6593 -1.3074 0.3895
s.e. 0.1598 0.1692 0.1267

sigma^2 estimated as 0.004155: log likelihood=1694.28
AIC=-3380.57 AICc=-3380.54 BIC=-3359.95

Training set error measures:
                        ME RMSE MAE MPE MAPE MASE
ACF1
Training set -0.0001262803 0.06436026 0.02635073 -0.008400937 0.3646559 1.40289 -
0.004595988

fore_log_pautoarima=forecast(log_pautoarima,h=10)
plot(fore_log_pautoarima)
```

Regards
Sherin

Comment: you need to use `exp()` on the predictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exp(forecast(log_pautoarima,h=10))
```

If you apply any function f to your data, when you predict with any kind of model, you need to trasform back to the original "scale" of the data with the inverse of f.

For the log function the inverse is the exp (exponential).